# Fill file content with variable received in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, text-processing

I have the following scenario: A unprivileged user should have the possibility to fill a certain file with new content. I do not want to grant him any rights to edit the file directly, so I gave him `sudo` rights to trigger a shell script, which will do the job in a safe manner: Receive the new content as `$1`, check it (not significant here) and write it to the destination file.

My Question: How could I write `$1` to another file while retaining all the special chars like `'$";\n`? It's a bit tricky because the content of `$1` could be a shell-script itself. I tried `echo "${1}" > destination_file.txt` within the script but that does not work.

Comment: What “didn’t work “ about it?

Comment: @JeffSchaller It's not passing the whole content 1:1 because of the special chars. Content gets cut away e.g.

Comment: @Norrius, I think I can't because the content must come from the script as the user does not have the rights to `cp` into the file.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question. Can you give an example of how you'd like to call the script? `./some.sh '#!/bin/bash\necho $1'`? I'm not sure what the expected flow here would be, but I would `mktemp` a new file, call open it in vim and after the user is done, move it to target place.

Comment: Actually I call the script from PHP: `shell_exec("/path/to/script.sh '{$content}'");`

Comment: Does it need to be `$1`? I think passing it as stdin will be much easier: `cat <<"EOF" '{$content}' EOF | ./script.sh` and then you can `cat > /etc/myfile` in the script. I'm not super sure if heredoc will work like this though.

Comment: Or, if PHP is able to pass arbitrary data to subshell's stdin, you could use that and skip that EOF nonsense.

Comment: @Norrius thanks dude, it somehow does not work. I think I have to grant rights.

Comment: Calling `sudo` on a shell script from PHP does not strike me as the most safest procedure...

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks. How to do it then?

Comment: If one of your users has access to a script via sudo, you should probably be aware that (at least on my box) the PATH environment variable is kept when running sudo. So in theory, if in your script you call, say, `cat` without the full path, and the user has changed its PATH to have its own home directory first, he can place an executable `cat` in there that will be run instead of the system one. This probably won't happen if you call sudo via PHP, but I don't think it's a good idea anyway.

Comment: @ChatterOne, thanks, +1, very useful information!